# Java Script not hiding DIV

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm having an issue trying to insert java scripts into an existing php page (which I didn't create).

What I'm trying to do is use a script that hides DIV's based on Dates. The div's have a lot of calls to PayPal for items that are time sensitive, and I'm trying to have the web page only display the currently available options.

Currently, I have this in the head: script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1 jquery.min.js"

/script

(I do have < and > before and after the code lines, but for some reason it won't let the line display on this post if I include them!)

I have this before the end of the body:

```
var now = new Date();
var futuretime1 = new Date("April 23, 2015 07:57:00");
var futuretime2 = new Date("April 23, 2015 07:58:00");
if(now > futuretime1)
 {
 $("#div1").hide();
if(now > futuretime2)
 {
 $("#div2").hide();
 }
</script>
```

This doesn't seem to even be recognized when the page runs in Firefox.

I've tried several different javascripts that are suppose to do the same thing, and none seem to be recognized.  I'm pretty new to coding, so I don't know where to go from here!

Could really use some ideas!

Comment: Are you sure you have elements with id "div1" and "div2", and **just one of each**?  If you re-use "id" values things won't work very well.

Comment: Could we see the html that you are trying to hide?

Comment: Your first `if` is missing a closing bracket `}`.

Comment: <div1>
 <td colspan=2><center>
 <form target="paypal" action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
 <table><tr><td align=center><i>Sign up for</i></td></tr><tr><td><input type="image" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_installment_plan_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay 

online!"></td></tr></table>
<img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
</form>
</td>
</tr>

</div1>

Comment: Code is too long to post it says.  Suffice it to say that the code between the div and /div tags ( of which there are only one set of div1 and div2 Pointy) sets up table rows.  I did add the brackets as Karl-Andre suggested. I'm not sure how to manually check the output FoX.

Answer (score 1):

You missed the closing bracket `}` of the `if` statement

```
if (now > futuretime1) {
    $("#div1").hide();
}
if (now > futuretime2) {
    $("#div2").hide();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check with `new Date().getTime()`

Using Timestamp for check time. I am not sure now time is equal to future time  in your point and you missed one close bracket for if

```
var now = new Date().getTime();
var futuretime1 = new Date("April 23, 2015 07:57:00").getTime();
var futuretime2 = new Date("April 23, 2015 07:58:00").getTime();

if(now > futuretime1)
 {
 $("#div1").hide();
} 
if(now > futuretime2)
 {
 $("#div2").hide();
 }
```

`alert(new Date().getTime());` // timestamp

Comment: Nothing I do seems to work. Is there a very simple javascript I can try on a new page to see if it works at all?  I can create a blank php page in the website.

Answer (score 0):

Missing bracket and try to use Date.parse it will give you correct result.

```
var now = new Date();
var futuretime1 = new Date("April 23, 2015 07:57:00");
var futuretime2 = new Date("April 23, 2015 07:58:00");


if( Date.parse(now) > Date.parse(futuretime1) )
{
    $("#div1").hide();
}
if(Date.parse(now) > Date.parse(futuretime2))
{
    $("#div2").hide();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I setup a codepen here http://codepen.io/michael-hamilton/pen/OVJZaz for you to check out.  Click "Test" to run the function that checks the dates and hides the divs.  I am having no issues with this working.  Make sure that your Javascript is targeting the correct HTML elements.  Make sure that the div ID that you want to hide is the same in the JS as in the HTML.

```
$("#div-1").hide();
```

You can verify this works in codepen by changing the future dates and and running the code again.

Also for the other commenters - I checked the values of `futuretime1` and `futuretime2` against `now` and they are all in the same format

Comment: Michael - does the div ID need the # as part of it as well?

Comment: no, the `id` attribute of the `div` does not need the the `#`.  The `#` is a selector that is used in CSS that signifies id.  jQuery uses these same selectors as well

Comment: your div element should look something like this: `<div id="div-1"></div>`

Comment: I can get your codepen to work, but copying it to a new php page and running it in Firefox gets me nothing.

Comment: Run this in Firefox, get nothing. :     <html>
 <head>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1 jquery.min.js">
 <script>
 function test(){
   var now = new Date();
   var futuretime1 = new Date("April 23, 2015 11:53:00");
   var futuretime2 = new Date("April 23, 2015 11:53:30");
   if(now > futuretime1){
    $("#div-1").hide();
   }
   if(now > futuretime2){
    $("#div-2").hide();
   }
 }
 $('#test').click(test);
</script> 
 </head>
 <body>

 <div id="div-1">
 div 1
 </div>

 <div id="div-2">
   div 2
 </div>

 <a href="javascript:;" id="test">Test</a>

 </body>
</html>

Comment: Make sure that you are loading jQuery before you run the script

Comment: you need to have a closing `</script>` tag after the jQuery script:
`<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1 jquery.min.js"></script>`

Answer (score 0):

```
You can do this way
```

// this will wrk perfectly

```
<?php
$today_date_time = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
var $futuretime1 = new Date("April 23, 2015 07:57:00");
var $futuretime2 = new Date("April 23, 2015 07:58:00");
?>
<script>
var now = '<?php echo strtotime($today_date_time)?>';
var futuretime1 = '<?php echo strtotime($futuretime1)?>';
var futuretime2 = '<?php echo strtotime($futuretime2)?>';
if(now>futuretime1)
{
$("#div1").hide();
}
if(now>futuretime2)
{
$("#div2").hide();
}
</script>
```

Comment: Neelesh - where should these be inserted?  My "script" is located just before the end of the body... should the <?php go in the head?

Comment: It can be added any where but should be at top of the script